# Rspec feature test. Page content doesn't differ among ordinary user and admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I'm new to testing.
I use **rspec-rails**, **factory_girl_rails** and **capybara** to test Rails 5 app.
For authentication I have **devise**.

My User model has additional field admin. By default admin is `false`. But first registered user becomes an administrator (`user.admin = true`).

Now when I do `user = create(:user)` in my test it creates an 'ordinary' user (`user.admin = false`)

But if I `puts page.body` I can see content which should not be rendered for an ordinary user.

Here is my template:

```
%menu
 %ul
   - if user_signed_in?
     %li
       Hey, #{current_user.name}
     %li= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path
     - if current_user.admin
       %li= link_to "Today's Orders", todays_orders_path
       %li= link_to "Registered Users", users_path
       %li= link_to "Add Dish", new_dish_path
     %li= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path
```

Feature test's snippet:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative '../support/authentication'

feature 'page content' do

  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  scenario 'show page content' do
    authentication = Authentication.new user
    authentication.sign_in

    puts page.body
  end
end
```

That's what puts return:

```
<menu>
<ul>
<li>
Hey, Test User
</li>
<li><a href="/users/edit">Edit Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="/todays_orders">Today&#39;s Orders</a></li>
<li><a href="/users">Registered Users</a></li>
<li><a href="/dishes/new">Add Dish</a></li>
<li><a href="/users/sign_out">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
</menu>
```

I suppose `current_user.admin` is ignored or something. But how to make it work properly?

**UPD**

That's interesting. First of all if I create one user and than `puts user.inspect` it shows:

`#<User id: 1, email: "user_1@example.com", name: "User_1", admin: false, created_at: "2016-09-06 15:15:31", updated_at: "2016-09-06 15:15:31">`

but if I use `(byebug)` the output shows that user.admin is set to true:

`(byebug) u = User.all
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, email: "user_1@example.com", name: "User_1", admin: true, created_at: "2016-09-06 15:15:31", updated_at: "2016-09-06 15:15:31">]>`

Next thing is if I create two users with:

`let(:admin) { create(:user) }
 let(:user) { create(:user) }`

and than sign in with `user` I still have all links available..
but if I create users like this:

`admin = User.create(name: 'admin', email: 'email_1@email.com', password: 123456, password_confirmation: 123456)
  user = User.create(name: 'user', email: 'email_2@email.com', password: 123456, password_confirmation: 123456)`

and sign is with `user`, everything works fine.

Comment: Ok we have more info now. Whats your model like? I am assuming all the admin logic is in there but you mention devise. The logic for assigning admin is important. For your first case where admin is false, have you confirmed a commit and do a reload.

Comment: Can you try with
`let!(:admin) ...`

Comment: let!(:admin) solved my case!

My model has all default Devises fields and two custom: name and admin.
In my User model I've defined a method:

`def set_admin
    User.first.update_attribute(:admin, true) if User.count == 1
  end`

which is executing by `after_create :set_admin` 

What does `let!` do? @Vangel

Comment: let! create a record immediately instead of lazy loading when :admin is explicitly called. At which point :admin may be called after a :user breaking the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests run on test database which is empty. The first user created is admin as you said so thats whats happening.  The tests are correct in that regard. You have to create a second user in your test to have an ordinary user.

You can use `byebug` inside the `'it'` block and then query to see that admin is set to true.

Edit: using `let!(:admin)` forces rspec to create the record immediately as opposed to lazy loading which is the default behaviour. When lazy loading the factory it is possible that :admin is being called :user and therefore not really :admin